# How to use if else condition in protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

In protractor i want to use if/else condition with javascript. Each steps need to be checked and if not get the element after wait go to else condition. for example

```
 selectPing() {
    element(by.xpath('//button[text()= "Ping"]')).click();
    expect(true).toBe(true);
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);

    var pingStatus = element(by.buttonText('Ok'));
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(pingStatus), 25000);
    pingStatus.click(); 
  }
```

In this snippet if i am not getting that 'Ok' button it will go to else condition how?

Comment: `if (pingStatus) pingStatus.click()`? Or does that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems browser.wait returns a promise so try to put a catch to intercept the timeout:

```
var pingStatus = element(by.buttonText('Ok'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(pingStatus), 25000).catch(function() {
    /* Do something if not getting the 'OK' button */
});
pingStatus.click();
```